# Retrieving data from Custom object to Select List using custom controller? Not getting any Output?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have following code

VF Page:

```
< apex:page controller="DisplayBooks">  
< apex:form >  
    < apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal}" size="1">   
    < apex:selectOptions value="{!openPresentationOptions}" />  
< /apex:selectList>  
< /apex:form>  
< /apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class DisplayBooks {  

    public String openPresentationOptions { get; set; }

    public String selectedVal { get; set; }       

    public List<SelectOption> getopenPresentationOptions(){    

         List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();           

        for(Books__c book : [SELECT Id,Name__c FROM Books__c]){

            options.add(new SelectOption(book.Id,book.Name__c));
        }
        return options;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be VF is getting the `openPresentationOptions` string, rather than `getopenPresentationOptions()`

try changing `getopenPresentationOptions()` to like `getPresentationOptions()`

and then change VF page to `< apex:selectOptions value="{!PresentationOptions}" />`

Comment: Thaks for help...its working

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove this line from apex class.

```
public String openPresentationOptions { get; set; }
```